# $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$

Tags: functions

Let $f$ be a function from the positive integers to the positive integers that satisfies the property: 
$$
f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)
$$
for all pairs of positive integers $(x,y)$.

If we are given that $f(2)=9$, what is the value of $f(5)$?

Comment: Nice try, what have you tried?

Comment: What is $f(1)$ under these conditions?

Comment: This is a live [math problem on Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/mathematics-problem/joaos-functional-equation/?group=hgiYzevHGNaU). Please close this for a week. - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master

Comment: I flagged it. Lets see what happens.

Comment: This question is a question on an open contest and the contest organisation has requested that it be closed until the contest finishes.

Answer (score 5):

$f(2) = f(1)^2 = 9$, what is $f(5) = f(1)^{5}$ then?

Comment: This is a live [math problem on Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/mathematics-problem/joaos-functional-equation/?group=hgiYzevHGNaU). Please close this for a week. - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$
f(2)=f(1)^2=9.
$$
Thus $f(1)=3$ and 
$$
f(5)=f(1)^5=3^5=243.
$$

Comment: This is a live [math problem on Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/mathematics-problem/joaos-functional-equation/?group=hgiYzevHGNaU). Please close this for a week. - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this is a live [math problem on Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/mathematics-problem/joaos-functional-equation/?group=hgiYzevHGNaU). Solutions are available. The image intentionally cuts off the first solution.

[image]