# Functional Equation (similar to Cauchy's): $ f ( x + y ) = f ( x ) f ( y ) + k x y ( x + y ) $

Tags: functional-equations

> Solve the following functional equation: $ k \in \mathbb R $, $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ and
> $$ f ( x + y ) = f ( x ) f ( y ) + k x y ( x + y ) \text , \forall x , y \in \mathbb R \text . $$

I have only got $ f ( 0 ) = 1 $, by letting $ f ( 0 ) = a $ and solving for $ a $.

If I use this, everything cancels out and leaves me with $ f ( x ) = f ( x ) $ which is fruitless.

Comment: Fix $y=0$. What happens then?

Comment: Let $$x=y$$ then $$f(2x) = (f(x))^2 +2kx^3$$

Comment: Let $$y=1$$ then $$f(x+1)=f(x)f(1) + kx(x+1)$$

Comment: There are two possible values for $$f(0)$$

Comment: @TheEpicPanada Note $k=0$ means your functional relation becomes $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$. [$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/529817) deals with just $N$ to $N$, [Question about $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1884903) deals with non-negative reals and [Derivated function $f$ so that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and $f'(x)f(y)=f(x)f'(y)$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1098490) deals with differentiable functions, so none cover all cases, but you may find them at least interesting, and possibly also useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch:**
Assume $k \ne 0$.

Note that
\begin{align}
f(x)f(-x)= f(0) = 1
\end{align}
then it follows $f$ is never zero and
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{1}{f(-x)}.
\end{align}
Also, we have that
\begin{align}
f(2x) = f(x)^2+2kx^3
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
1=&\ f(2x)f(-2x) \\
=&\ (f(x)^2+2kx^3)(f(-x)^2-2kx^3) \\
=&\ (f(x)^2+2kx^3)(\frac{1}{f(x)^2}-2kx^3)\\
=&\ 1+\frac{2kx^3}{f(x)^2}-2kx^3f(x)^2-4k^2x^6
\end{align}

Hence
\begin{align}
&0=2kx^3f(x)^4+4k^2x^6f(x)^2-2kx^3\\
&\implies f(x)^4+2kx^3f(x)^2-1=0
\end{align}

So, we have that
\begin{align}
f(x)^2=\frac{-2kx^3\pm \sqrt{4k^2x^6+4}}{2}= -kx^3\pm \sqrt{k^2x^6+1}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sqrt{\sqrt{k^2x^6+1}-kx^3}.
\end{align}

However, by plugging $f$ back into the functional equation, we immediately arrive at a contradiction. Hence $f(x)^4+2kx^3f(x)^2-1\ne 0$, which means $k = 0$. This reduces the functional equation to $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$, which means $f(x) = e^{cx}$.

Comment: Hey @JackyChong, when I submit this my friend says to think about the problem more
because there is a mistake. He says the problem is somewhere in $\sqrt{\sqrt{k^2 x^6+1}+kx^3}$

Comment: The formula you've found is derived by the assumption $k\ne0$. You can put it in the functional equation and do the messy calculations, only to get a contradiction. That means it cannot be true, thus we must have $k=0$, and hence $f$ must satisfy Cauchy's exponential functional equation.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari Yes. That's correct. I got to check the validity of the solution when I toss out the $2kx^3$ factor.